# iOS: How to set camera flash is ON when open camera?

Tags: ios, camera

When open camera I want camera flash is turned on NOT Auto. Can I do that? 
Any advice is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Flash has no control over camera flash - you will need to use an Adobe Native Extension (ANE) to control it (not sure if anyone has already written one).

Comment: @LeeBurrows Where was Adobe Flash mentioned?

Comment: Ahh. I bet it was the tag. Removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help ya out. Include the second line when you're about to present your camera to the user:

```
UIImagePickerController *iPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
iPicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOn;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works well. Beside that I want to hide camera icon (front & rear) when open camera. I only want to use rear camera. Can I do that? Thanks.